# How to create a Snackbar like in the material documentation?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-snackbar, snackbar

I've seen this new Snackbar Style in the Outlook for Android app and now looked for it in the Material Documentation:

https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html

Does anybody know how to create those "offset Snackbars"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to create those "offset Snackbars"?

You can get the `LayoutParams` of SnackBar and add **Bottom** and **Side** Margin to it

Try out like code below

```
public static void showSnackbar(Snackbar snackbar, int sideMargin, int marginBottom) {
    final View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
    // Depend upon your parent Layout Use `LayoutParams` of that Layout
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) snackBarView.getLayoutParams();

    params.setMargins(params.leftMargin + sideMargin,
                params.topMargin,
                params.rightMargin + sideMargin,
                params.bottomMargin + marginBottom);

    snackBarView.setLayoutParams(params);
    snackbar.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you also know how I can make those rounded corners?

Comment: You maybe able to do that using creating rounded corner `shape` drawable and setting it as background of snackbar

Answer (score 2):

There are only three things you need to do to build a rounded SnackBar like Material:

1. getLayoutParams of SnackBar and set the margins
2. create a rounded corner shape
3. set round corner shape as a background for the SnackBar

Here is the complete code:

```
Snackbar.make(
            findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout),
            "Your text here",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).apply {
            view.layoutParams = (view.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
                setMargins(
                    12,
                    12,
                    12,
                    12
                )
            }
            view.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_corner, null)
        }.show()
```

and here is the code for round corner drawable in drawable/round_corner:

```
  <shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#323232"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the new Material theme. 
In your build.gradle import
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'`

Change all your Snackbar import to:

`import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar`

Then in your style.xml file your parent theme needs to be one of the material themes:

`Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`

`Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 1):

I added those styles from https://material.io/develop/android/components/snackbars/

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/Widget.App.Snackbar</item>
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.SnackbarButton</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.Snackbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Snackbar</item>
    <item name="actionTextColorAlpha">1</item>
  </style>

<style name="Widget.App.SnackbarButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/shrine_pink_100</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Snackbar" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/shrine_pink_100</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/shrine_pink_900</item>
</style>
```

and it works! Modifying code/layout/background programmatically didn't work work me

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the default `Snackbar` in the Material Components Library:

[image]

If you want to change the margin of the `Snackbar` you can add in your app theme the `snackbarStyle` attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/MySnackbar</item>
</style>
```

with:

```
<style name="MySnackbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">32dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]